Can't figure out why my loginController can't authenticate the user. Spring Security driving me nuts
Made a lot of edits. Didn't set springsecuritycontext earlier.
This is the error I'm getting:
2024-07-05T02:37:01.443-04:00 TRACE 46690 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-5] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on POST /login_success using AuthorityAuthorizationManager[authorities=[USER]]
2024-07-05T02:37:01.443-04:00 TRACE 46690 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 78D83992116FD8443A13A27376BEA891 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2024-07-05T02:37:01.444-04:00 TRACE 46690 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-07-05T02:37:01.444-04:00 TRACE 46690 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-5] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-07-05T02:37:01.444-04:00 TRACE 46690 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=78D83992116FD8443A13A27376BEA891], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-07-05T02:37:01.444-04:00 TRACE 46690 --- [fitBuddyApp] [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=78D83992116FD8443A13A27376BEA891], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

This is my UserDetails via CustomUserDetails
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user;
    private int id;

    private String username;

    Role user_role;

    private String email;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public CustomUserDetails(User user) {

    }


    public CustomUserDetails(int id, String getusername, String role, String password, String email, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.user_role = Role.valueOf("USER");
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRoles().toString());
        return Arrays.asList(authority);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getusername();
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

This is my CustomUserDetailsService.
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getusername(), user.getPassword(), getAuthorities(user));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        // Example: Fetching user roles and converting them to GrantedAuthority
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
        });
        return authorities;
    }

This is my loginController. I'm trying to implement securityContext.


@Controller
public class loginController {
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private final SecurityContextHolderStrategy securityContextHolderStrategy =
        SecurityContextHolder.getContextHolderStrategy();

private final SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository =
        new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();

private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpServletResponse response;

PasswordEncoder bcrypt = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

UserRepository userRepository;


public loginController(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login(Model model) {
    return "login";
}


@PostMapping("/login_success")
public String processLogin(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password,
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {


    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER");
    User user = new User();
    user.setusername(username);
    userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    user.setPassword(password);


    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
            username, password, authorities);

    authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

    SecurityContext securityContext = this.securityContextHolderStrategy.createEmptyContext();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(token);
    this.securityContextHolderStrategy.setContext(securityContext);
    this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(securityContext, request, response);

    return "redirect:/login_success";
}

And here is my security configuration:
@EnableWebSecurity // have to add or it can't find HttpSecurity type
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {



        http
                .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home", "/confirmation").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login_success").hasAuthority("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()


                )

                .securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                        .requireExplicitSave(true)
                )


                .formLogin(form ->
                        form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .usernameParameter("username")
                                .passwordParameter("password")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/login_success")
                                .permitAll()

                )
                .logout(l -> l
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()


                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService,
                                                       PasswordEncoder encoder) {

        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);

        return new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider);
    }


Is it better to implement the securitycontextholder in the security config?
Been following these docs and can't seem to find guidance on how to use for custom login point for spring 6.1+.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/migration/servlet/session-management.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html#servlet-authentication-authenticationprovider
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/persistence.html#httpsecuritycontextrepository

After authentication (since you have chosen to write your own login endpoint) you need to store the authentication object in the SecurityContext. This is documented in authentication architecture chapter.

please do not post code in comments, cant you see its unreadable, use the edit button on your question. And also, always include updated debug/trace logs with every update.

I made a change to my login configuration
public class loginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}

and the security config
 public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/home", "/confirmation").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/profile").permitAll()
                )

                .formLogin(form->
                        form
                                .loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/processlogin")
                                .defaultSuccessUrl("/profile")
                                .permitAll()


                )
                .logout(l -> l
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true)

Works now.

your constructors in class CustomUserDetails seems incorrect. You are taking values in parameterized constructor but body is empty, which you are calling from build function as well and your non-parametrized constructor is setting values but don't have any params so they are setting to them selves.
fix them like this:
    public CustomUserDetails( ) {
        
    }
    
    public CustomUserDetails(int id, String getusername, String role, String password, String email, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.role = role;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }


